# gsutil copy to storage failing

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

i'm working in a instance at us-central1-a zone and I can't copy a ~200GB file.

i've tried :

- gsutil -m cp -L my.log my.file gs://my-bucket/
- gsutil -m cp -L my.second.log my.file gs://my-bucket2/

And after several "catch ups" I get the following error:

CommandException: Some temporary components were not uploaded successfully. Please retry this upload.
CommandException: X files/objects could not be transferred.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a message you'll see if gsutil's [parallel composite uploads feature](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads) fails to upload at least one of the pieces of the file.

A couple of questions...

1. Have you already tried performing this upload again, after you saw this message?
2. If this error persists, could you please provide the stack trace from `gsutil -d cp...`

If you're consistently seeing this error and need an immediate fix (if this is a bug with parallel uploads), you can set `parallel_composite_upload_threshold=0` in the `GSUtil` section your boto config to disable parallel uploads.

Comment: 1. Yes, many times
2. I'm doing it right now. 
thanks for your answer. What do i have to clean in this stack trace before pasting it here?

Comment: To be safe - please redact any authorization headers, bearer tokens, etc., and then send it to gs-team@google.com (with a link to this stackoverflow question) rather than posting here.

Comment: Hello, sorry for taking so long.
As the problem was in one instance and it was generating costs i've migrated de disk to a develop instance and i was able to copy the file from it, so i guess we will never know what the issue was. Thank you for your help and if it happens again i'll bring de diagnostic/debug output already.

Comment: Is there a reason why `gsutil -m` might creates such problem? I have done 171 transfers in 171 instances respectively, and 80 have such problems `CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.`. And it doesn't tell which file could not be transferred. Also, does it mean that `gsutil cp` is safer than `gsutil -m`, meaning such problem won't happen?

Comment: Known Serious bug https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/279
In short.... use the -L option any time you do a large job

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message. I tried login in to gcloud again with

```
gcloud auth login
```

and then I could run the command successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience using gsutil. I fixed by installing the crcmod.

First run the command you have issues with using the debug flag, for example:

```
gsutil -d -m cp gs://<path_to_file_in_bucket>
```

In the output I can see:

```
CommandException: Downloading this composite object requires integrity checking with CRC32c, but your crcmod installation isn't using the module's C extension, so the hash computation will likely throttle download performance. For help installing the extension, please see "gsutil help crcmod".

To download regardless of crcmod performance or to skip slow integrity checks, see the "check_hashes" option in your boto config file.

NOTE: It is strongly recommended that you not disable integrity checks. Doing so could allow data corruption to go undetected during uploading/downloading.
```

You can follow the instructions here from google to install crcmod for your specific os: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CRC32CandInstallingcrcmod